# PyQt5 focusing on readonly QLineEdit widgets

Tags: python, pyqt

I have 3 QLineEdit widgets that are readonly and listen to keyevents. Well I want to let the user to choose what QLineEdit he is going to use(because it's going to be a shortcut setting window). It appears when in readonly mode the widget is non-clickable. Is there a way to make it clickable or do the same thing without readonly?

I made the code in Qt Designer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(392, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent1

        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 150, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent2
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 220, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent3
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def newOnkeyPressEvent1(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
        keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
        print(keyname)
        self.lineEdit.setText(str(keyname))

    def newOnkeyPressEvent2(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
        keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
        print(keyname)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(str(keyname))

    def newOnkeyPressEvent3(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
        keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
        print(keyname)
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(str(keyname))

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I tested your code and these qlineedits look click-able.

Comment: Well in my computer, I can't see any difference when I click QLineEdit. And if  it's clickable why doesn't the keyevent work on the QLineEdit I click on?

Comment: Because you have `MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent1` line 3 times, you don't do anything with `event2` or `event3`.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Thats a typo made while make a new project for this question. when I change that to ```self.newOnkeyPressEvent1```, ```self.newOnkeyPressEvent2```, ```self.newOnkeyPressEvent3``` it only works in the last QLineEdit.

Comment: Yes, because the last `MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent3` overrides previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine which lineedit is under focus with `self.centralwidget.focusWidget()`. Here is full working code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(392, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 70, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        MainWindow.keyPressEvent = self.newOnkeyPressEvent

        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 150, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")

        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 220, 113, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def newOnkeyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        modifiers = int(event.modifiers())
        keyname = QtGui.QKeySequence(modifiers + key).toString()
        print(keyname)
        lineEdit = self.centralwidget.focusWidget()
        lineEdit.setText(str(keyname))

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```